# Search for a long list of names in SQL

Tags: sql, search

I have a CSV list with a few thousand names (first, last) and I would like to search for them in SQL. How can I do this easiest?

Edit: I'm using oracle obiee so I'm somewhat limited. Not sure if I can just load a csv into a temporary table since my access is limited. Will try this tomorrow at work since I just left. Using join on it sounds quite clever to my beginner ears though.

Comment: The most general solution is to load the data into a table and use a `join`.

Comment: Too short description. Please give more details, examples, what you already tried...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up doing

```
WHERE 'first name'||'last name'||'first name' LIKE '%john%smith%'
```

The first name is concatenated both at beginning and end so that it mathes both 'john smith' and 'smith john'.

Answer (score 0):

Follow these steps

1. Import CSV files into your SQL server of your choice.
2. Use the following sql statement: `select * from <table name> where <last name column> = 'smith';`